# Trying to test DocumentSnapshot but when I do an when(documentSnapshot.exists()).thenReturn(true) always return false Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, mockito, junit5, junit-jupiter

I'm trying to test a method that validate that the record exist and another operation but the most important is that if exist and I'm mocking everything that I need but when mock that call to the exists method from DocumentSnapshot always get false, could there a reason that this happens or may my mock is not created in a good way.

Method to test

```
@Override
    public boolean recordExists(String primaryKey, String payload, Map<String, String> headers) {
        try {
            if (this.db == null) {
                setupConnection();
            }

        if (this.db != null) {
            if (this.config.getPrimaryKeyValuePrefix() != null
                    && this.config.getPrimaryKeyValuePrefix().length() > 0) {
                primaryKey = this.config.getPrimaryKeyValuePrefix() + primaryKey;
            }
            if (this.config.getPrimaryKeyValueSuffix() != null
                    && this.config.getPrimaryKeyValueSuffix().length() > 0) {
                primaryKey += this.config.getPrimaryKeyValueSuffix();
            }

            DocumentReference docRef = this.db.collection(this.config.getTableName()).document(primaryKey);
            ApiFuture<DocumentSnapshot> future = docRef.get();

            DocumentSnapshot document = future.get();
            if (document.exists()) {

                if (this.config.getOutOfOrderValidationRequired()) {
                    // check if this message is out of order
                    boolean isOutOfOrder = isRecordOutOfOrder(document, payload, headers);
                    if (isOutOfOrder) {
                        LOG.info(
                                "FirestoreDB recordExists() document is found and message is out of order. PrimaryKey is "
                                        + primaryKey + " and payload is " + payload);
                    }

                    return isOutOfOrder;
                } else {
                    LOG.info("FirestoreDB recordExists() document is found. PrimaryKey is " + primaryKey
                            + " and payload is " + payload);
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        ex.printStackTrace(pw);
        LOG.error("FirestoreDB setupConnection() exception " + sw.toString());
    }

    return true;

}
```

Test created

```
 @Test
    public void recordExistTest() throws JsonProcessingException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        configMap.put(ConfigUtils.DLQ_DATABASE_CONFIG,
                "{ \"databaseType\": \"firestore\", \"projectId\": \"data-test\", \"tableName\": \"test\", \"primaryKeyPath\": \"key\", \"primaryKeyValuePrefix\": \"test\",  \"outOfOrderValidationRequired\": \"true\"}");
        dlqDatabaseConfig =  objectMapper.readValue(this.configMap.get(ConfigUtils.DLQ_DATABASE_CONFIG),
                DatabaseConfig.class);
        FirestoreDB firestoreDB = new FirestoreDB(dlqDatabaseConfig);
         DocumentReference documentReference = mock(DocumentReference.class);
         ApiFuture<DocumentSnapshot> apiFuture = mock(ApiFuture.class);
         DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = mock(DocumentSnapshot.class);

        when(documentReference.get()).thenReturn(apiFuture);
        when(apiFuture.get()).thenReturn(documentSnapshot);
        when(documentSnapshot.exists()).thenReturn(true);
        when(documentSnapshot.get("myField")).thenReturn("myValue");

        assertEquals(true, documentSnapshot.exists());
        assertTrue(firestoreDB.recordExists(anyString(), anyString(), anyMap()));

    }
```

I got and assertion error because the `when(documentSnapshot.exists()).thenReturn(true);` is returning false even if I'm indicating to be true, what could be the reason? thanks in advance.

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52)
    at org.rf.kafka.common.databases.FirestoreDBTest.recordExistTest(FirestoreDBTest.java:49)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
```

Comment: don't mock the intermediate objects (why should you?) rather mock (or setup!) `this.db.collection(this.config.getTableName()).document(primaryKey);` returning "real (customized) objects"

Comment: I'm mocking the DocumentReference because the this.db attribute is private in the class and I'm not able to access it in the test and I'm not sure if I can modify this

Comment: according to your log the **assertTrue(firestoreDB.recordExists(anyString(), anyString(), anyMap())); ** is failing.  See  **org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52)**